# Given a convergent power series in x, can one prove the equivalent power series in (1-x) is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a certain infinite power series: $S(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+ \ldots$, which is defined for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and I have reasons to assume that it is convergent for all such $x$. Is there any way to prove that if one rewrites this series in the form $S(1-y) = b_0+b_1y+b_2y^2+b_3y^3+ \ldots$ then the infinite expressions (sums) for $b_0, b_1, b_2,$ etc. obtained from this equality are all convergent, and the series in powers of $y$ is convergent, too?  I only have approximate numerical values for $a_0, a_1, a_2,$ etc. up to $a_{120}$ (don't have any closed form formula for them).

Leszek

Answer (score 1):

We have $b_0 = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j$ which converges by assumption. But already $b_1 = \frac d{dy} S(1-y)|_{y=0} = -S'(1) = -\sum_{j=1}^\infty ja_j$ which might or might not converge. Take for example
$$
S(x) = x+(1-x)\log(1-x) = \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j(j-1)}
$$
which converges for all $|x|\le1$; however,
$$
S'(x) = -\log(1-x) = \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{x^{j-1}}{j-1}
$$
which doesn't converge at $x=1$.